# Implementing a HashTable in Swift?

Tags: swift, hashtable, hashcode

I'm trying to implement a HashTable in Swift. Base on my understanding the hash values are used as the index to be used in the array. The problem is hash values are very large numbers for example.

```
"1" => 4,799,450,059,485,597,623
"2" => 4,799,450,059,485,597,624
"3" => 4,799,450,059,485,597,629
```

What's the correct way of using these hash values to generate an array index?

```
class HashTable <K: Hashable, V> {

    private var values : [V?]

    init(size: Int) {
        values = [V?](count: size, repeatedValue: nil)
    }

    func push(key: K, value: V?) {
        values[key.hashValue] = value
    }

    subscript (key: K) -> V? {
        get {
            return values[key.hashValue]
        }
        set {
            push(key, value: newValue)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A Swift Dictionary _is_ a hash table, so what's the advantage of reimplementing it as an array? (Especially given the fact that Swift doesn't have sparse arrays...)

Comment: @matt I know that, The advantage of implementing your own is learning how they work. Doesn't my code create a sparse array? [V?](count: size, repeatedValue: nil) an array of a  specific size with default value of nil

Comment: This article seems to solve this http://waynewbishop.com/swift/hashtables

Answer (score 1):

I ended up storing LinkedNodes in the array instead of the value.

```
hashIndex = hashValue % values.count
```

when searching, or deleting if there are more than one node in the LinkedList, I compare the hashValues directly instead of the hashIndex. (Handle Collision)

Wondering if there is a better solution

Comment: Hi, You can go through below link this might be helpful :  https://github.com/raywenderlich/swift-algorithm-club/tree/master/Hash%20Table